# boost::asio readsome function does not seem to work

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am currently experiencing troubles using boost::asio, I want to write and read like in the following piece of code. Write works fine, but reading always returns zero. Actually I also found out that every site refers to the

> read_some

function instead of the

> readsome

function I have on my system in the library ...

Anybody who can give me a hint on this?

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream tcp_stream;
tcp_stream.connect("localhost", "12345");

while(1)
{
    char inp[6]={0,0,0,0,0,0};

    tcp_stream<<"Test"<<std::endl;//Works fine get it with netcat (nc -l 12345)

    size_t r = tcp_stream.readsome(inp,5);//Always 0

    //std::string a;
    //tcp_stream>>a; //Works but blocks and gives me all bytes it has.
    //std::cout<<a<<std::endl;

    //std::cout<<"RDBUF: "<<tcp_stream.rdbuf();
    //rdbuf blocks here, never resuming and outputting 
    //everything I write with netcat to command line...
    if(r>0)
    {
        std::cout<<inp<<std::endl;
    }

    else //<<< always goes here
    {
        std::cout<<"received nothing!"<<std::endl;


    }
    sleep(1);
}
```

What I would like to have is that I read 0-5 bytes from the current interface. (non-blocking)

Comment: Having had that discussion a few times on the job, while I failed there to convince others, I highly doubt that non-blocking is the way to go. Not only because it ends up in spinning threads which could otherwise sleep, which is wasteful (energy, trees, ...). Also, I cannot fathom why so many think non-blocking IO facilitates things.

Comment: @BitTickler Non-blocking I/O does not imply or require spinning. Perhaps you are conflating it with polling?

Comment: @rhashimoto Non-blocking is polling basically - how else would you know data is available?

Comment: @BitTickler The same way blocking calls are ultimately notified: by device interrupt.

Comment: @rhashimoto In most modern OS, an interrupt causes a interrupt service thread (or microthread) to be scheduled. That threat is also not polling the interrupt status - the ISR interacts with the scheduler. In the same sense, user space threads are either in state "running" or "waiting" (or other states, here not relevant). If you do blocking call, the thread transits to "waiting" and once the event is triggered, the scheduler places the thread back into the running queue. If you do non-blocking IO the thread state is not affected.

Comment: @BitTickler Yes...that's what I said - blocking calls are ultimately notified by device interrupt. Non-blocking calls are also notified by device interrupt. The interrupt may result in setting a flag which user-level code can poll. But the interrupt can instead result in invoking a user-supplied handler - that's non-blocking I/O without polling. And good asynchronous I/O code typically never spins. It generally still blocks; it just blocks when it decides that it can't proceed. Have you actually used `boost::asio` (in an asynchronous manner)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115669/discussion-between-rhashimoto-and-bittickler).

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `std::basic_istream<>::read_some()` will read from the associated `streambuf`'s input sequence, and the [`asio::basic_socket_streambuf`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_streambuf.html)'s input sequence includes data that has been read from the socket, but not yet consumed from the streambuf.  It does not include data that is available to be read from the socket without blocking.<sup>[1]</sup>

To work around this behavior, one could determine the amount of data available to be read without blocking from both the streambuf and its underlying socket, then issue a `std::basic_istream<>read()` operation:

```cpp
/// @brief Read up to `n` characters from `stream` and store them
///        into `buffer` without blocking.  This may not read all
///        of the requested amount of bytes.
template <typename... Args>
std::streamsize readsome(
  boost::asio::basic_socket_iostream<Args...>& stream,
  char* buffer,
  std::streamsize n)
{
  std::streamsize available =
    stream.rdbuf()->in_avail()     // available on input sequence
    + stream.rdbuf()->available(); // available on socket
  n = std::min(n, available);
  if (n == 0) return 0;

  stream.read(buffer, n);
  return n;
}
```

---

Here is a complete example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/184c6e1f4698267d) this functionality:

```cpp
#include <chrono>     // std::chrono::seconds
#include <iostream>   // std::cout, std::endl
#include <string>     // std::to_string
#include <thread>     // std::thread
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

/// @brief Read up to `n` characters from `stream` and store them
///        into `buffer` without blocking.  This may not read all
///        of the requested amount of bytes.
template <typename... Args>
std::streamsize readsome(
  boost::asio::basic_socket_iostream<Args...>& stream,
  char* buffer,
  std::streamsize n)
{
  std::streamsize available =
    stream.rdbuf()->in_avail()     // available on input sequence
    + stream.rdbuf()->available(); // available on socket
  n = std::min(n, available);
  if (n == 0) return 0;

  stream.read(buffer, n);
  return n;
}

int main()
{
  using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

  const std::array<char, 6> expected_data = {100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105};

  // Create all I/O objects.
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 0));
  tcp::socket socket(io_service);

  // Run stream in its own thread.
  std::thread client_thread(
    [&]
    {
      // Connect the stream to the acceptor.
      auto endpoint = acceptor.local_endpoint();
      tcp::iostream stream(endpoint.address().to_string(),
                           std::to_string(endpoint.port()));

      // Block until 6 bytes are available.
      while (stream.rdbuf()->available() < 6)
      {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
      }

      // Read 1 byte out of the 6 avaialble.
      std::array<char, 6> actual_data{};
      auto bytes_transferred = readsome(stream, begin(actual_data), 1);
      assert(bytes_transferred == 1);
      assert(std::equal(
        begin(actual_data),
        begin(actual_data) + bytes_transferred,
        begin(expected_data)));

      // Attempt to read 6 bytes, although only 5 are available.
      bytes_transferred = readsome(stream, begin(actual_data),
                                   sizeof actual_data);
      assert(bytes_transferred == 5);
      assert(std::equal(
        begin(actual_data),
        begin(actual_data) + bytes_transferred,
        begin(expected_data) + 1));

      // Attempt to read 6 more bytes, even though 0 bytes are available.
      bytes_transferred = readsome(stream, begin(actual_data),
                                   sizeof actual_data);
      assert(bytes_transferred == 0);
    });

  // Connect the sockets then write to the stream.
  acceptor.accept(socket);
  boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(expected_data));

  // Wait for the stream to complete.
  client_thread.join();
}
```

---

<sub>1. The [`tcp::stream`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/iostream.html) documentation and its related classes are not well documented.  I am not versed enough to know if this behavior is intentional, a bug, or has merely been overlooked.  The documentation still remains fairly terse in the current [networking-ts draft](https://github.com/cplusplus/networking-ts).</sub>